# How can we find a 3d sdf file if there is no in PubChem?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I'm looking for a 3d sdf file of BBr3.
Though I cheked PubChem, there is no 3d file, but there is a 2d file.

In that case, how can I get a 3d file, are there any other repositry on 3d file?

or below is acceptable?

```
    mol = Chem.SDMolSupplier("2d-sdf file", removeHs=False)
    # compatible with "removeHs=False"
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol) 

    params = ETKDGv3() 
    params.randomseed = 1
    EmbedMolecule(mol, params) # expand mol to 3d
```

best regards!

Comment: You may want to include what you are doing. This doesn't appear to be code that actually runs. Also you might want to include the file you are looking at. The geometry of the module is actually quite simple, there are probably 3d coordinates in a different database.

Comment: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/geom1x.asp

Comment: BBr3 is symmetrical planar so you can edit the 2D data and add a z column  and  make each value  zero. (Levy & Brockway JACS 1937, p2085,v59). The B-Br bond length is 0.187 nm, so in fact this is all that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comemnt. I automatically download e.g. BBr3 via pubchempy https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/CID/25134/record/SDF?record_type=2d&response_type=display and I'm use above code for structure optimixation before calculating wafe-function. Is this proper way? Sorry for my beginner question.

Comment: Looks like ordinary 3d coordinates to me. I really don't understand what problem you are facing. You should [edit] your question to make it more clear. Also, this appears to be a better fit at [mattermodeling.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a SMILES string (`BrB(Br)Br`), a program like [openbabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel) (its most recent documentation [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UseTheLibrary/Python.html)) can

```shell
obabel -:"BrB(Br)Br" --gen3d -osdf -xv2000
```

generate a conformer (described [here](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/SingleConformer.html))* for you. *As such*, the approach is not this much different to the one PubChem uses – their 3D conformer preview equally is an affordable guess about an isolated molecule without any influence by a solvent molecule, or other neighbors (e.g., packing as in crystals).

If you don't have a SMILES string in hand, nor an other structure file openbabel can process to yield a SMILES string for you: ChemDraw's [sample page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html) allows to draw small molecules which can be exported in this representation (structure -> get smiles) by copy-paste.

Kim, S.; Bolton, E. E.; Bryant, S. H. PubChem3D: Conformer Ensemble Accuracy. *J. Cheminform.* **2013**, *5*, 1. https://doi.org/10.1186/1758-2946-5-1 (open access).

* OpenBabel's default is MMFF94 you can adjust to other force fields ([entry](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Forcefields/Overview.html)).  They differ in coverage of atoms / patterns encoded in parameters.  With more flexible molecules, the program's search for [multiple conformers](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/multipleconformers.html) is a helpful tool, too.

Comment: Dear martin, porphyrin, buttonwood. Thank you for your kind comemnt. I got saficient infomation, probaly. Originally, I just would like to know whether a 2d-sdf file is available for psi4 structure optimization after it is epanded to a 3d model via EmbedMolecule

Comment: In this particular case (boron) Open Babel will use UFF since there are no MMFF94 parameters for boron.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Because Open Babel automatically looks up for a force field suitable and the specialty of boron here, I now think the explicit call `obabel -:"BrB(Br)Br" --gen3d -osdf -xv2000 --minimize --ff MMFF94` (which, by lack of parameters, fails) vs `obabel -:"BrB(Br)Br" --gen3d -osdf -xv2000 --minimize --ff UFF` (no error report) is the better approach (for that the limitations are prominently reported). On the other hand I assumed `--gen3d` and `--minimize` as two separate actions, where `--minimize` works with the results obtained by `--gen3d`. Do you recommend the second approach?

Comment: I personally would prefer it, to clear up the question first before answering. Now it'll sit here with a negative score, unappealing and closed, with an answer that in my personal opinion does not really address the actual problem. The pubchem file is ok, there is no need for a different strategy.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン If, as moderator, you think the neither one is for the benefit of chem.se I can agree to a clean-up which removes question and answer altogether.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize again that I was sharing my personal preference, i.e. in the capacity of an ordinary user. I was somewhat invested in the question and I'm slightly disappointed that this led nowhere. This is of course no fault or yours. In my capacity as a moderator I see no reason to step in at all.